# Por que o "unsigned int" não é compatível com o CLS?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, runtime

Descobri que o tipo `unsigned int` e outros tipos sem sinal não recebem a compatibilidade de CLS, ou seja, outras linguagens usadas no .NET podem não entender esses tipos, ao contrário dos tipos que estão específicas no CLS que obrigatoriamente devem estar presentes para a linguagem como um todo ter compatibilidade com o .NET.

E o que fazer quando precisa conversar com uma linguagem que não tem um tipo desses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse tipo de pergunta é interessante porque o que mais importa ao bom programador é saber o porquê das coisas, mais do que só saber o que fazer. Mas ao mesmo tempo é complicado de responder porque só os criadores do .NET sabem responder. Ou pior ainda, nem eles. A explicação do motivo não está na documentação.

O que nós podemos inferir é que algumas linguagens que poderiam estar presentes no .NET desde sua concepção não tinham esses tipos e não poderia obrigar elas a criar um tipo para se conformar, ou teriam que ser declaradas incompatíveis com o .NET, pelo menos no todo.

Pra mim isso mostra que essas tentativas de fazer plataformas que sirvam para várias linguagens não funcionam de fato, no fim, ou as linguagens se tornam muito parecidas ou possuem muitas limitações, especialmente de interoperabilidade, o que faz a plataforma que queria ser multi-linguagens não ter muito sentido. Esse é só um motivo que mostra que não funciona tão bem quanto acham que vai funcionar.

E a solução é a mesma dada por outras tecnologias de interoperabilidade, você tem que converter para outro tipo de informação, e achar um mecanismo específico em cada caso para compensar se tiver perda de informação na conversão, o que pode ser um enorme problema.

Sei que parece pouco, mas é só isso. A questão maior é a ideia original, que eu acho errado, de tentar fazer várias linguagens funcionarem juntas, só funciona bem se as linguagens forem praticamente idênticas. É a crítica que faço ao .NET e que faz o C# ter um pouco de defeito. Se abrissem mão dessas cosias o C# poderia se desenvolver melhor.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/language-independence?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).